# Why answered questions are getting bumped

Tags: discussion

Why questions that have been answered by me or other people are being bumped by 'community'. I see a lot of questions that have been answered correctly, just the person asking the question didn't marked it as solved. Answers given to the questions cover everything there is nothing else to be said.

Comment: Could you provide a link to a specific example? That might help clarify what issue you're trying to address.

Comment: Not right now. From my phone I don't see bumped posts. But you can check posts that are answered by Solar Mike he gives good answer and still post getting bumped.

Comment: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/50891/bmw-x-1-2014-steering-wheel-vibration-over-60mph
like why this is bumped? It has reasonable answer and it's almost 1 year old post

Comment: If the poster would make the effort to accept a valid answer, unless they are just taking the answer and running, that would reduce the number of these questions getting "community" bumped...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've asked this question before after seeing questions pop up to the top wondering, "*Who drives the **Community ♦** login in and why?*" The answer I received was thus about the questions popping.

Community is a completely automated process. It looks for questions which have languished on the site and moves them up to the top by modifying them slightly (or updating the "modified" time in the database), which then pops it to the top. What Community considers as a question which has languished is one which hasn't been answered. To be considered answered by the system, it requires one of two things. First (the obvious one) is when the OP selects an answer as "thee" answer. Second, independent of the OP's selection, if a single answer has been upvoted. As per [this Meta.SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/249769):

> Note that the posts eligible for bumping are those scoring >= 0 that have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one non-deleted answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be deleted or closed).

If a Q/A meets these criteria, Community views it as fair game and will bump it.

So, one or several of the questions you've answered have been clicked to the top in this manner. There's not much we can do about that now. What we can do about it going forward is to ensure we are voting on not only questions, but answers as well. I realize we cannot vote on our own Q/A's, but we can vote on others', so I encourage all to use up their (up to) 40 votes per day. There is lots of content on the site which deserves it ... if it's points you're after personally, voting on other people's stuff brings votes your way. I don't know why it works that way, but it does (well, good answers help here as well :o).

Comment: The complete rule is [mentioned on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/241919): "*Note that the posts eligible for bumping are those scoring >= 0 that have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one non-deleted answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be deleted or closed).*"

Comment: In that case we should upvote more, that way we won't get flooded with already answered questions.

Comment: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/50891/bmw-x-1-2014-steering-wheel-vibration-over-60mph
like why this is bumped? It has reasonable answer and it's almost 1 year old post

Comment: @AsenM - Because it had not been upvoted or selected as the answer. Just as AndrewT. posted above ... I'll update my answer just a little bit to reflect it.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 So, should the algorithm be altered to post a reminder to the OP to accept the answer or one answer **before** it just bumps it on the stack?

Comment: @SolarMike - If you are suggesting SE should change how **Community ♦** behaves, then by all means suggest it on Meta. If you believe we should change how we behave, that's a lot easier. A single upvote on an answer would prevent it from being brought to the front by **Community ♦**. If there is no answer, an answer with a subsequent upvote will prevent it. If the question is unanswerable, put a close vote on it.