# Posts automatically bumped by Community, nudging OP first?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there an argument to have the algorithm / process for posts that will normally be automatically bumped by Community altered so that the Original Poster gets a reminder that they have not accepted an answer to their question? ie they get a "gentle" nudge...

I have read this Q&A : [Why answered questions are getting bumped](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2025/10976)
which sparked this thought, as this may help the completion of questions.

Comment: This really is a question for [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). You may want to look through the [list of questions surrounding the Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-user) to see if something like this has already been asked. There's nothing the mods here on Mech can do about it directly. Sorry if I wasn't explicit about it in your other post here on Mech.Meta, but that was my intention.

Comment: All good, thanks for replying, cheers. Will look there.

Comment: If you believe this would not get shot down or closed as a dupe on Meta.SE, I can just transfer it for you. Let me know what you'd like to do.

Comment: From a quick look, I have not seen that suggestion -there are several hundred though.. So, please transfer it on my behalf, I'll take the hit !

Comment: I've brought this up over on a Moderators only chat because I was having issues moving the question. The Community Manager who was present told me not to move it, but rather, let it be fleshed out here. If *our* community can see value in this and how it should be done, then I'd have you re-ask the question over on Meta.SE with a link back to your question here. That way they can see what's going on and how we think it should be handled, without the need to bring it up SE wide if the community here finds it not necessary. Hopefully that makes sense. To that end, I'll bump it to the front page.

Comment: I stumbled upon this meta post... and looks like an interesting idea. While on the first thought I see it as a good idea, I wonder what about [this question on Anime.SE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/27524/revisions): the question has been bumped per month for 27 times since it was posted! However, while there is no problem with the answer, it's also not convincing enough for the asker & community to judge & vote it. Will it be noise for the OP? Now, this is only 1 question... The next thing is, of course, not to force OP to accept/upvote existing answers that aren't useful for them...

Comment: @AndrewT. Well, I get the two points you add, thanks for reading and commenting.

Comment: And while they're at it, perhaps they could check if the OP has even been seen, in, oh... maybe the last 3 years.